# Iterate over *args?

Tags: python, arguments

I have a script I'm working on where I need to accept multiple arguments and then iterate over them to perform actions. I started down the path of defining a function and using `*args`. So far I have something like below:

```
def userInput(ItemA, ItemB, *args):
    THIS = ItemA
    THAT = ItemB
    MORE = *args
```

What I'm trying to do is get the arguments from `*args` into a list that I can iterate over. I've looked at other questions on StackOverflow as well as on Google but I can't seem to find an answer to what I want to do. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To get your **precise** syntax:

```
def userInput(ItemA, ItemB, *args):
    THIS = ItemA
    THAT = ItemB
    MORE = args
    
    print THIS,THAT,MORE
    
    
userInput('this','that','more1','more2','more3')
```

You remove the `*` in front of `args` in the assignment to `MORE`. Then `MORE` becomes a tuple with the variable length contents of `args` in the signature of `userInput`

Output:

```
this that ('more1', 'more2', 'more3')
```

As others have stated, it is more usual to treat `args` as an iterable:

```
def userInput(ItemA, ItemB, *args):    
    lst=[]
    lst.append(ItemA)
    lst.append(ItemB)
    for arg in args:
        lst.append(arg)

    print ' '.join(lst)
    
userInput('this','that','more1','more2','more3')
```

Output:

```
this that more1 more2 more3
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to `lst.extend(args)`?

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> def foo(x, *args):
...   print "x:", x
...   for arg in args: # iterating!  notice args is not proceeded by an asterisk.
...     print arg
...
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x: 1
2
3
4
5
```

**edit:** See also [How to use *args and **kwargs in Python](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) (As referenced by Jeremy D and subhacom).

Answer (score 4):

If you do that :

```
def test_with_args(farg, *args):
    print "formal arg:", farg
    for arg in args:
        print "other args:", arg
```

Other information: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

```
MORE = args
```

Or, directly:

```
for arg in args:
    print "An argument:", arg
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I iterate over `args`", then the answer is "the same way you iterate over anything": `for arg in args: print arg`.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over `args`:

```
def userInput(ItemA, ItemB, *args):
    THIS = ItemA
    THAT = ItemB
    for arg in args:
        print arg
```