# Can't get values out of a function within a function for an iterating variable after returning values for that function

Tags: python

I'm having problems with trying to get values out of a function for a for loop iterating variable within a function with the same name. Sorry if that was hard to comprehend, but here it is.

```
blog_1 = "Hello"
blog_2 = "I am a man"
blog_3 = "i am living"

def my_blogs(*args):
    return(args)
    for blog in my_blogs:
        print(blog)

my_blogs(blog_1, blog_2, blog_3)
```

It's probably really simple for you guys so I'm sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: As soon as you call `return` the function is going to end. So it will never reach the loop

Comment: When you `return` from a function, the code thereafter will not be touched. Either think of `yield` or rethink your whole problem.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to put the `return` as the last line of the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over \*args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569092/iterate-over-args)

Comment: No matter where you put the return you'll receive an error as my_blogs is a function not an iterable

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "iterating variable within a function with the same name"? What do you intend to do? Your variables and function don't share the same name.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to print out the blog variables through the use of functions, and I know I could do so by doing a for loop taking values out of the arg parameter but i just wanted to try taking them out of the function itself, but like someone else said, it just isn't iterable i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate over `my_blogs` because it's a function. Also, the `return` statement ends the function immediately. Move it to the end of the function. Working code:

```py
def my_blogs(*args):
    for blog in args:
        print(blog)
    return args
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now! (:

Comment: No matter where you put the return you'll receive an error as my_blogs is a function not an iterable

Comment: function returns iterable object, `args` is `tuple`

Answer (score 0):

`return` should be written at the end of the function

```
blog_1 = "Hello"
blog_2 = "I am a man"
blog_3 = "i am living"

def my_blogs(*args):
    for blog in args:
        print(blog)
    return(args)

my_blogs(blog_1, blog_2, blog_3)
```

Comment: No matter where you put the return you'll receive an error as my_blogs is a function not an iterable

Comment: function returns iterable object, `args` is `tuple`

Comment: ```for blog in my_blogs``` is an erroneous line. the Type of my_blogs is a func, func is not itterable. This code will not execute